# Changing Table of contents direction in word 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, table-of-contents

I'm using word 2010 and I'm trying to create a TOC for a right-to-left language. The problem is that word creates the TOC as left-to-right, meaning that the chapter names are on the left side and the page numbers on the right.

Can it be changed?

thx

Answer (score 7):

After you create the TOC in word:

1. Select the text in the table, and right click on it.
2. Choose **Paragraph** from the menu.
3. In the **General** sector under the **Indents and Spacing** tab, choose **Direction**: **Right-to-left**.

This worked for me.

Comment: It's working, though leaving it in the same language - which is good only if you aren't trying to switch between a left-to-right language to right-to-left language in addition to changing the direction of the text.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Well, it did but whenever I refresh the table it goes back to RTL

Comment: I found this question via Google. What worked for me is to open the Page Setup dialog (under Page Layout - Page Setup) and choose the Section Direction as Right to Left. This even reconstructs the ToC as roght to left even when I "Update the whole table" instead of just updating the page numbers.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the table of contents
2. Navigate to **Layout -> Page Setup -> Layout**
3. In **Section -> Section Direction** Select **Right-to-left**.

This worked for me on Microsoft 365.

[image]

I have done this multiple times and it works. This was suggested by [asibahi](https://superuser.com/users/1126955/asibahi) in a comment to the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/747968/1049034) by [Mohmad El-Yamani](https://superuser.com/users/319442/mohmad-el-yamani) but it was never in a answer, so **credits go to [asibahi](https://superuser.com/users/1126955/asibahi)**.

When I tried the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/747968/1049034) by [Mohmad El-Yamani](https://superuser.com/users/319442/mohmad-el-yamani) to choose Right-to-left in the Paragraph menu, it worked more or less OK, but there were some indentation problems and when I updated the table of contents, it changed back to Left-to-right and I had to change it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking under the "File > Options > Language > Choose Editing Languages"

Answer (score 0):

«Try looking under the "File > Options > Language > Choose Editing Languages"» (thanks to hinekyle answer) then create a new document and move your content into it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all the Content.
2. Right Click.
3. Paragraph.
4. Set as Default.
5. This Document only.

NOTE-*It work if your default Microsoft Word install was in English. :)*

Answer (score -1):

In addition to "hinekyle & Ebrahim Byagowi" answers,

just copy your contents to the new document by select all of content, DO NOT copy it with ctrl+A, otherwise it will copy the old TOC format as well.

"""Works with me on Word 2013""" ---> apparently this would works fine with a small size document's content.

And the nice part of that method, you do not need to change TOC direction to "Right-to-Left" each time when you update the entire table (as that is not one of MS Word default options).

Comment: Do those other answers not work for you?  If they don’t, say so (by asking a new question, linking to this one).  If they do, why give an answer suggests something clunky like copying the entire document contents into a new document?  (In real life, that’s more work than you make it seem.)  And what, exactly, do you mean by «select all with "shift" button,»?